# Facebook Android sdk 3.1 is returning only 10 friends via FQL?

Tags: android, facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-fql

Previously I used to get entire friends list via GraphObject, but now only 10 are being returned. Is there any work around ?

Here is my code:

```
        String fqlQuery = "SELECT uid,name,pic_square FROM user WHERE uid IN (SELECT uid2 FROM friend WHERE uid1 = me() )";

        final Bundle params = new Bundle();
        params.putString("q", fqlQuery);

        Request request = new Request(session,  "/fql",  params, HttpMethod.GET, new Request.Callback()

        { 
          public void onCompleted(Response response) 
             {
                //Log.i("listttt:::::", "Got results: " + response.toString());
               try
               {
                GraphObject graphObject = response.getGraphObject();
                JSONObject jsonObject = graphObject.getInnerJSONObject(); 


                Log.v("Fb frn list size:::::", ""+jsonObject .length());  



               }catch(Exception e){
                    e.printStackTrace();
               }
            }
            });

            //Request.executeBatchAsync(request);

        RequestAsyncTask task = new RequestAsyncTask(request);
        task.execute();
```

Answer (score 0):

If your app was set up before April 30th 2014, you can specify that you explicitly want to use v1.0, which will give you all friends. This will only work until April 30th, 2015. If the app was created later, there's no possibility to get all friends. Have a look on the highlights of FB API upgrade.
According to this 

***4. All friend_* permissions have been removed
In v1.0, it was possible to ask for permissions that would allow an app to see a limited amount of friend data, such as a person's friend's likes, their birthdays, and so on.***

In v2.0, those permissions have all been removed. It's no longer possible for an app to see data from a person's friends unless those friends have also logged into the app and granted permission for the app to see it that data.

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api